# Lagrangian for spring mass pulley systems

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, spring

Recently I came across a question relating to a spring mass system with pulleys. So I decided to try and write its Lagrangian. However I have run into a problem. The expression for a spring's potential energy involves the extension in the spring. However I am unable to create proper variables that accomplish to do so.

[image: The Question involving multiple springs and pulleys]

$x_p$ represents the pulley positions, while x represents the position of the mass.

Could someone help me with creating the proper variables to write the Lagrangian for this system?

Comment: Can you provide the source for this problem?

Comment: The question is to find the time period of oscillations for this system

Comment: Pulley 2 the spring and the rope don’t work together, instead of the rope you can put another spring, for this system i can write you the equations